# indexed_db - objectstore.delete - onSuccess

Tags: dart

Could someone please tell me what's wrong with the following code. The main problem is that the line :

```
fDbListAllClients;    // this is not being "called"
```

appears not to be executed.

There may be other erroneous code, also. I'm not concerned as to whether it is necessary to check for deletion, I'm wanting to know what is causing the problem with non-execution of the line in question.

```dart
fDbDeleteOneClient(String sKey) {
  var oDbTxn      =  ogDb1.transaction(sgTblClient, 'readwrite');
  var oDbTable    =  oDbTxn.objectStore(sgTblClient);
  var oDbRecord   =   oDbTable.getObject(sKey);
  oDbRecord.onSuccess.first.then((val) {if (oDbRecord.result == null) {
    window.alert("Record $sKey not found and cannot be deleted");
    return;}});
  var oDbDelReq   =  oDbTable.delete(sKey);
  oDbDelReq.onSuccess.first.then((val1) {
    var oDbRecord   =   oDbTable.getObject(sKey);  // check if it was deleted
    oDbRecord.onSuccess.first.then((val2){
      if (oDbRecord.result != null) {
        window.alert("Record $sKey was found but cannot be deleted");
      }
    });
    fDbListAllClients;    // this is not being "called"
  });  
  oDbDelReq.onError.first.then((e) => window.alert(
    "Error on Delete of $sKey. Error = ${e}"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem or the main problem is that one needs to use onSuccess.listen(). As someone answered on another question :

"onSuccess is a stream. If you want to receive more than one element just "listen" for them: onSuccess.listen."